# Mask for an Input to allow phone numbers?

Tags: angular, forms, input

Is it possible to have model-driven form in Angular 2 and implement a directive that would allow to mask an `input` field like a phone number entry `(123) 123-4567`?

Comment: If you are still looking other alternative then Refer InputMask from PrimeNG here - http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/mask

Comment: Here is another plugin:  https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask

Comment: @brando all of the solutions I found online require you to install a third-party npm package. Does Angular 11 not have its own package for something like this? I'm really curious you see.

Answer (score 93):

**Angular5 and 6:**

angular 5 and 6 recommended way is to use @HostBindings and @HostListeners instead of the host property

remove host and add  **@HostListener**

```
 @HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event'])
  onModelChange(event) {
    this.onInputChange(event, false);
  }

  @HostListener('keydown.backspace', ['$event'])
  keydownBackspace(event) {
    this.onInputChange(event.target.value, true);
  }
```

Working Online stackblitz Link: https://angular6-phone-mask.stackblitz.io

Stackblitz Code example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-phone-mask

Official documentation link https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#respond-to-user-initiated-events

**Angular2 and 4:**

[**Plunker >= RC.5**](https://plnkr.co/edit/oali7nSuuV8If06NvyGF?p=preview)

**original**

One way you could do it is using a directive that injects `NgControl` and manipulates the value

(*for details see inline comments*)

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel][phone]',
  host: {
    '(ngModelChange)': 'onInputChange($event)',
    '(keydown.backspace)': 'onInputChange($event.target.value, true)'
  }
})
export class PhoneMask {
  constructor(public model: NgControl) {}

  onInputChange(event, backspace) {
    // remove all mask characters (keep only numeric)
    var newVal = event.replace(/\D/g, '');
    // special handling of backspace necessary otherwise
    // deleting of non-numeric characters is not recognized
    // this laves room for improvement for example if you delete in the 
    // middle of the string
    if (backspace) {
      newVal = newVal.substring(0, newVal.length - 1);
    } 

    // don't show braces for empty value
    if (newVal.length == 0) {
      newVal = '';
    } 
    // don't show braces for empty groups at the end
    else if (newVal.length <= 3) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})/, '($1)');
    } else if (newVal.length <= 6) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})/, '($1) ($2)');
    } else {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(.*)/, '($1) ($2)-$3');
    }
    // set the new value
    this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(newVal);       
  }
}
```

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
  <form [ngFormModel]="form">
    <input type="text" phone [(ngModel)]="data" ngControl="phone"> 
  </form>
  `,
  directives: [PhoneMask]
})
export class App {
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      phone: ['']
    })
  }
}
```

[**Plunker example <= RC.5**](https://plnkr.co/edit/hWpNz1QYCBpTzKjXtnOr?p=preview)

Comment: It fails when we put maxlength in html. For example i don't want users to add characters more than 10. I put maxlength=10 and it only allows (111)(11)

Comment: That's exactly 10 characters :D (with a space between `) (`. You have to take the formatting characters into account.

Comment: I used: this.model.control.setValue(); to set the model value and this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(); to set the view value.

Comment: How can I get input like hh:mm:ss:SSS?

Comment: If I follow the stackblitz example for Angular 5/6, I have a problem -- if a valid phone number is entered, despite the mask preventing additional input, the form control is made invalid.  Here's a fork of the example addiing validation -- https://angular6-phone-mask-uytj4e.stackblitz.io/.  Just enter numbers until you reach 10 digits, and the mask will present 111/111-1111.  Try to enter an 11th digit, you'll see the field turn red despite the additional input being hidden.  How can one re-trigger validation after the directive alters the value?

Comment: why do you need a host listener on backspace? How could you use this with a ControlValueAccessor?

Comment: That's quite an old answer of mine. I hoped there would be better options/answers by now. I don't know a better way. I haven't worked with Angular since a while.

Answer (score 43):

I Think the simplest solutions is to add [ngx-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask)

```
npm i --save ngx-mask
```

then you can do

```
<input type='text' mask='(000) 000-0000' >
```

OR

```
<p>{{ phoneVar | mask: '(000) 000-0000' }} </p>
```

Comment: I tried to use some of the more upvoted answers but had some odd bugs. ngx-mask is an incredibly popular package. Currently has about 40,000 downloads per week! Way easier to use this, thanks.

Comment: You may need to use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50729114/ionic3-cant-bind-to-textmask-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-ion-input, which basically suggest importing it in a module lower than the app module is the key.

Comment: We need to import NgxMaskModule.                                                                             import { NgxMaskModule, IConfig } from 'ngx-mask';                                                            
                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                             
imports: [
    NgxMaskModule.forRoot(),
  ],

Comment: We're up to 574k downloads/month. That's a lotta downloads a month.

Comment: this sould be the accepted answer, we don't need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: IMO Using packages that apparently are maintained by a single person can be a valid alternative but I wouldn't go so far as to call it the default accepted answer for a question like this. We would do well to be way more cautious about importing open source packages in any solution.

Answer (score 18):

### Angular 4+

I've created a **generic directive**, able to **receive any mask** and also able to **define the mask dynamically** based on the value:

*mask.directive.ts:*

```js
import { Directive, EventEmitter, HostListener, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

import { MaskGenerator } from '../interfaces/mask-generator.interface';

@Directive({
    selector: '[spMask]' 
})
export class MaskDirective {

    private static readonly ALPHA = 'A';
    private static readonly NUMERIC = '9';
    private static readonly ALPHANUMERIC = '?';
    private static readonly REGEX_MAP = new Map([
        [MaskDirective.ALPHA, /\w/],
        [MaskDirective.NUMERIC, /\d/],
        [MaskDirective.ALPHANUMERIC, /\w|\d/],
    ]);

    private value: string = null;
    private displayValue: string = null;

    @Input('spMask') 
    public maskGenerator: MaskGenerator;

    @Input('spKeepMask') 
    public keepMask: boolean;

    @Input('spMaskValue') 
    public set maskValue(value: string) {
        if (value !== this.value) {
            this.value = value;
            this.defineValue();
        }
    };

    @Output('spMaskValueChange') 
    public changeEmitter = new EventEmitter<string>();

    @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
    public onInput(event: { target: { value?: string }}): void {
        let target = event.target;
        let value = target.value;
        this.onValueChange(value);
    }

    constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) { }

    private updateValue(value: string) {
        this.value = value;
        this.changeEmitter.emit(value);
        MaskDirective.delay().then(
            () => this.ngControl.control.updateValueAndValidity()
        );
    }

    private defineValue() {
        let value: string = this.value;
        let displayValue: string = null;

        if (this.maskGenerator) {
            let mask = this.maskGenerator.generateMask(value);

            if (value != null) {
                displayValue = MaskDirective.mask(value, mask);
                value = MaskDirective.processValue(displayValue, mask, this.keepMask);
            }   
        } else {
            displayValue = this.value;
        }

        MaskDirective.delay().then(() => {
            if (this.displayValue !== displayValue) {
                this.displayValue = displayValue;
                this.ngControl.control.setValue(displayValue);
                return MaskDirective.delay();
            }
        }).then(() => {
            if (value != this.value) {
                return this.updateValue(value);
            }
        });
    }

    private onValueChange(newValue: string) {
        if (newValue !== this.displayValue) {
            let displayValue = newValue;
            let value = newValue;

            if ((newValue == null) || (newValue.trim() === '')) {
                value = null;
            } else if (this.maskGenerator) {
                let mask = this.maskGenerator.generateMask(newValue);
                displayValue = MaskDirective.mask(newValue, mask);
                value = MaskDirective.processValue(displayValue, mask, this.keepMask);
            }

            this.displayValue = displayValue;

            if (newValue !== displayValue) {
                this.ngControl.control.setValue(displayValue);
            }

            if (value !== this.value) {
                this.updateValue(value);
            }
        }
    }

    private static processValue(displayValue: string, mask: string, keepMask: boolean) {
        let value = keepMask ? displayValue : MaskDirective.unmask(displayValue, mask);
        return value
    }

    private static mask(value: string, mask: string): string {
        value = value.toString();

        let len = value.length;
        let maskLen = mask.length;
        let pos = 0;
        let newValue = '';

        for (let i = 0; i < Math.min(len, maskLen); i++) {
            let maskChar = mask.charAt(i);
            let newChar = value.charAt(pos);
            let regex: RegExp = MaskDirective.REGEX_MAP.get(maskChar);

            if (regex) {
                pos++;

                if (regex.test(newChar)) {
                    newValue += newChar;
                } else {
                    i--;
                    len--;
                }
            } else {
                if (maskChar === newChar) {
                    pos++;
                } else {
                    len++;
                }

                newValue += maskChar;
            }
        }       

        return newValue;
    }

    private static unmask(maskedValue: string, mask: string): string {
        let maskLen = (mask && mask.length) || 0;
        return maskedValue.split('').filter(
            (currChar, idx) => (idx < maskLen) && MaskDirective.REGEX_MAP.has(mask[idx])
        ).join('');
    }

    private static delay(ms: number = 0): Promise<void> {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms)).then(() => null);
    }
}
```

*(Remember to declare it in your NgModule)*

The numeric character in the mask is `9` so your mask would be `(999) 999-9999`. You can change the `NUMERIC` static field if you want (if you change it to `0`, your mask should be `(000) 000-0000`, for example).

The value is displayed with mask but stored in the component field without mask (this is the desirable behaviour in my case). You can make it be stored with mask using `[spKeepMask]="true"`.

The directive receives an object that implements the `MaskGenerator` interface.

*mask-generator.interface.ts:*

```js
export interface MaskGenerator {
    generateMask: (value: string) => string;
}
```

This way it's possible to **define the mask dynamically** based on the value (like credit cards).

*I've created an utilitarian class to store the masks, but you can specify it directly in your component too.*

*my-mask.util.ts:*

```js
export class MyMaskUtil {

    private static PHONE_SMALL = '(999) 999-9999';
    private static PHONE_BIG = '(999) 9999-9999';
    private static CPF = '999.999.999-99';
    private static CNPJ = '99.999.999/9999-99';

    public static PHONE_MASK_GENERATOR: MaskGenerator = {
        generateMask: () =>  MyMaskUtil.PHONE_SMALL,
    }

    public static DYNAMIC_PHONE_MASK_GENERATOR: MaskGenerator = {
        generateMask: (value: string) => {
            return MyMaskUtil.hasMoreDigits(value, MyMaskUtil.PHONE_SMALL) ? 
                MyMaskUtil.PHONE_BIG : 
                MyMaskUtil.PHONE_SMALL;
        },
    }

    public static CPF_MASK_GENERATOR: MaskGenerator = {
        generateMask: () => MyMaskUtil.CPF,
    }

    public static CNPJ_MASK_GENERATOR: MaskGenerator = {
        generateMask: () => MyMaskUtil.CNPJ,
    }

    public static PERSON_MASK_GENERATOR: MaskGenerator = {
        generateMask: (value: string) => {
            return MyMaskUtil.hasMoreDigits(value, MyMaskUtil.CPF) ? 
                MyMaskUtil.CNPJ : 
                MyMaskUtil.CPF;
        },
    }

    private static hasMoreDigits(v01: string, v02: string): boolean {
        let d01 = this.onlyDigits(v01);
        let d02 = this.onlyDigits(v02);
        let len01 = (d01 && d01.length) || 0;
        let len02 = (d02 && d02.length) || 0;
        let moreDigits = (len01 > len02);
        return moreDigits;      
    }

    private static onlyDigits(value: string): string {
        let onlyDigits = (value != null) ? value.replace(/\D/g, '') : null;
        return onlyDigits;      
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in your component (use `spMaskValue` instead of `ngModel`, but if is not a reactive form, use `ngModel` with nothing, like in the example below, just so that you won't receive an error of no provider because of the injected `NgControl` in the directive; in reactive forms you don't need to include `ngModel`):

*my.component.ts:*

```js
@Component({ ... })
export class MyComponent {
    public phoneValue01: string = '1231234567';
    public phoneValue02: string;
    public phoneMask01 = MyMaskUtil.PHONE_MASK_GENERATOR;
    public phoneMask02 = MyMaskUtil.DYNAMIC_PHONE_MASK_GENERATOR;
}
```

*my.component.html:*

```
<span>Phone 01 ({{ phoneValue01 }}):</span><br>
<input type="text" [(spMaskValue)]="phoneValue01" [spMask]="phoneMask01" ngModel>
<br><br>
<span>Phone 02 ({{ phoneValue02 }}):</span><br>
<input type="text" [(spMaskValue)]="phoneValue02" [spMask]="phoneMask02" [spKeepMask]="true" ngModel>
```

*(Take a look at `phone02` and see that when you type 1 more digit, the mask changes; also, look that the value stored of `phone01` is without mask)*

I've tested it with normal inputs as well as with `ionic` inputs (`ion-input`), with both reactive (with `formControlName`, not with `formControl`) and non-reactive forms.

Comment: Hi, I´m recieving a error "Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'spMaskValue' since it isn't a known property of 'input'." I´m new in angular (using angular 4), and i´m creating a project with jhipster. I think I forgot to add some lib or something. Can you give me any tips?

Comment: @Rodrigo You must make sure that the module that includes the directive is imported in the module of the component that uses it. Let's say that the module `MaskDirectiveModule` includes the `MaskDirective` in its `declarations` array, and that `MyComponentModule` includes `MyComponent` (the component in which you use `spMaskValue`). Then, make sure that `MyComponentModule` imports `MaskDirectiveModule`.

Answer (score 11):

I do this using the **TextMaskModule** from '**angular2-text-mask**'

Mine are split but you can get the idea

**Package using NPM NodeJS**

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular2-text-mask": "8.0.0",
```

**HTML**

```
<input *ngIf="column?.type =='areaCode'" type="text" [textMask]="{mask: areaCodeMask}" [(ngModel)]="areaCodeModel">


<input *ngIf="column?.type =='phone'" type="text" [textMask]="{mask: phoneMask}" [(ngModel)]="phoneModel">
```

**Inside Component**

```
public areaCodeModel = '';
public areaCodeMask = ['(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, ')'];

public phoneModel = '';
public phoneMask = [/\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/];
```

Comment: FYI: this is no longer maintained and should avoid using it unless you feel you can fix any issues that arise.

Answer (score 10):

### Reactive Form

---

**[See at Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular5-phone-mask-directive)**

Addition to the **@Günter Zöchbauer**'s answer above, I tried as follows and it seems to be working but I'm not sure whether it is a efficient way.

I use `valueChanges` observable to listen for change events in the reactive form by subscribing to it. For special handling of backspace, I get the `data` from subscribe and check it with `userForm.value.phone(from [formGroup]="userForm")`. Because, at that moment, the data changes to the new value but the latter refers to the previous value because of not setting yet. If the data is less than previous value then the user should remove character from input. In this case, change pattern as follows:

from : `newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})/, '($1)');`

to : `newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})/, '($1');`

Otherwise, as Günter Zöchbauer mentioned above, deleting of non-numeric characters is not recognized because when we remove parentheses from input, digits still remain the same and added again parentheses from pattern match.

**Controller:**

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup,FormBuilder,AbstractControl,Validators } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) { 
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm(){
    this.userForm = this.fb.group({
      phone:['',[Validators.pattern(/^\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}$/),Validators.required]],
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.phoneValidate();
  }

  phoneValidate(){
    const phoneControl:AbstractControl = this.userForm.controls['phone'];

    phoneControl.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
    /**the most of code from @Günter Zöchbauer's answer.*/

    /**we remove from input but: 
       @preInputValue still keep the previous value because of not setting.
    */
    let preInputValue:string = this.userForm.value.phone;
    let lastChar:string = preInputValue.substr(preInputValue.length - 1);

    var newVal = data.replace(/\D/g, '');
    //when removed value from input
    if (data.length < preInputValue.length) {

      /**while removing if we encounter ) character,
         then remove the last digit too.*/
      if(lastChar == ')'){
         newVal = newVal.substr(0,newVal.length-1); 
      }
      if (newVal.length == 0) {
        newVal = '';
      } 
      else if (newVal.length <= 3) {
        /**when removing, we change pattern match.
        "otherwise deleting of non-numeric characters is not recognized"*/
        newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})/, '($1');
      } else if (newVal.length <= 6) {
        newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})/, '($1) $2');
      } else {
        newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(.*)/, '($1) $2-$3');
      }
    //when typed value in input
    } else{


    if (newVal.length == 0) {
      newVal = '';
    } 
    else if (newVal.length <= 3) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})/, '($1)');
    } else if (newVal.length <= 6) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})/, '($1) $2');
    } else {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(.*)/, '($1) $2-$3');
    }

  }
    this.userForm.controls['phone'].setValue(newVal,{emitEvent: false});
  });
 }

}
```

**Template:**

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm"  novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="tel">Tel:</label>
    <input id="tel" formControlName="phone" maxlength="14">
  </div>
  <button [disabled]="userForm.status == 'INVALID'" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

**UPDATE**

> Is there a way to preserve cursor position while backspacing in the middle of the string? Currently, it jumps back to the end.

Define an id `<input id="tel" formControlName="phone" #phoneRef>`
and [renderer2#selectRootElement](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#selectRootElement) to get the *native element* in the component.

So we can get the cursor position using:

```
let start = this.renderer.selectRootElement('#tel').selectionStart;
let end = this.renderer.selectRootElement('#tel').selectionEnd;
```

and then we can apply it after the input is updated to new value:

```
this.userForm.controls['phone'].setValue(newVal,{emitEvent: false});
//keep cursor the appropriate position after setting the input above.
this.renderer.selectRootElement('#tel').setSelectionRange(start,end);
```

**UPDATE 2**

> It's probably better to put this sort of logic inside a directive
>   rather than in the component

I also put the logic into a directive. This makes it easier to apply it to other elements.

**[See at Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular5-phone-mask-directive)**

***Note:*** It is specific to `(123) 123-4567` pattern.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done using a directive. Below is the plunker of the input mask I built.

https://plnkr.co/edit/hRsmd0EKci6rjGmnYFRr?p=preview

Code:

```
import {Directive, Attribute, ElementRef, OnInit, OnChanges, Input, SimpleChange } from 'angular2/core';
import {NgControl, DefaultValueAccessor} from 'angular2/common';

@Directive({
selector: '[mask-input]',
host: {
    //'(keyup)': 'onInputChange()',
    '(click)': 'setInitialCaretPosition()'
}, 
inputs: ['modify'],
providers: [DefaultValueAccessor]
})
export class MaskDirective implements OnChanges {
maskPattern: string;
placeHolderCounts: any;
dividers: string[];
modelValue: string;
viewValue: string;
intialCaretPos: any;
numOfChar: any;
@Input() modify: any; 

constructor(public model: NgControl, public ele: ElementRef, @Attribute("mask-input") maskPattern: string) {
    this.dividers = maskPattern.replace(/\*/g, "").split("");
    this.dividers.push("_");
    this.generatePattern(maskPattern);   
    this.numOfChar = 0;
}

ngOnChanges(changes: { [propertyName: string]: SimpleChange }) {
    this.onInputChange(changes);
}

onInputChange(changes: { [propertyName: string]: SimpleChange }) {             
    this.modelValue = this.getModelValue();
    var caretPosition = this.ele.nativeElement.selectionStart;
    if (this.viewValue != null) {
      this.numOfChar = this.getNumberOfChar(caretPosition);
    }
    var stringToFormat = this.modelValue;        

    if (stringToFormat.length < 10) {
        stringToFormat = this.padString(stringToFormat);
    }

    this.viewValue = this.format(stringToFormat);

    if (this.viewValue != null) {
        caretPosition = this.setCaretPosition(this.numOfChar);
    }

    this.model.viewToModelUpdate(this.modelValue);
    this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(this.viewValue);
    this.ele.nativeElement.selectionStart = caretPosition;
    this.ele.nativeElement.selectionEnd = caretPosition;
}

generatePattern(patternString) {
    this.placeHolderCounts = (patternString.match(/\*/g) || []).length;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.placeHolderCounts; i++) {
        patternString = patternString.replace('*', "{" + i + "}");
    }
    this.maskPattern = patternString;
}

format(s) {
    var formattedString = this.maskPattern;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.placeHolderCounts; i++) {
        formattedString = formattedString.replace("{" + i + "}", s.charAt(i));
    }
    return formattedString;
}

padString(s) {
    var pad = "__________";
    return (s + pad).substring(0, pad.length);
}

getModelValue() {
    var modelValue = this.model.value;
    if (modelValue == null) {
        return "";
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < this.dividers.length; i++) {
        while (modelValue.indexOf(this.dividers[i]) > -1) {
            modelValue = modelValue.replace(this.dividers[i], "");
        }
    }
    return modelValue;
}

setInitialCaretPosition() {
    var caretPosition = this.setCaretPosition(this.modelValue.length);

    this.ele.nativeElement.selectionStart = caretPosition;
    this.ele.nativeElement.selectionEnd = caretPosition;

}

setCaretPosition(num) {
    var notDivider = true;
    var caretPos = 1;
    for (; num > 0; caretPos++) {
      var ch = this.viewValue.charAt(caretPos);
      if (!this.isDivider(ch)) {
        num--;
      }
    }
    return caretPos;
}

isDivider(ch) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.dividers.length; i++) {
          if (ch == this.dividers[i]) {
              return true;
          }
    }
}

getNumberOfChar(pos) {
  var num = 0;
  var containDividers = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
    var ch = this.modify.charAt(i);

    if (!this.isDivider(ch)) {
      num++;
    }
    else {
      containDividers = true;
    }
  }
  if (containDividers) {
    return num;
  }
  else {
    return this.numOfChar;
  }
}
```

}

Note: there are still a few bugs.

Comment: Did you update to rc4, can you please update code in plunk

Comment: Nice one-thanks, added below in onInputChange() method to restrict input max to place holder counts :
if (stringToFormat.length > this.placeHolderCounts)
            stringToFormat = stringToFormat.substr(0, this.placeHolderCounts);

Answer (score 2):

Combining Günter Zöchbauer's answer with [good-old vanilla-JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29335409/5116121), here is a  directive with two lines of logic that supports *(123) 456-7890* format.

**Reactive Forms:** [Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/KGWk0iAm2I45pnF68Ar8)

```
import { Directive, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import { NgControl } from "@angular/forms";

@Directive({
  selector: '[formControlName][phone]',
  host: {
    '(ngModelChange)': 'onInputChange($event)'
  }
})
export class PhoneMaskDirective {

  @Output() rawChange:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor(public model: NgControl) {}

  onInputChange(value) {
        var x = value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
        var y = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');

        this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(y);
        this.rawChange.emit(rawValue); 
  }
}
```

**Template-driven Forms**: [Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/QxU8l3vHw8BZhrzbSDqJ)

```
import { Directive } from "@angular/core";
import { NgControl } from "@angular/forms";

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel][phone]',
  host: {
    '(ngModelChange)': 'onInputChange($event)'
  }
})
export class PhoneMaskDirective {

  constructor(public model: NgControl) {}

  onInputChange(value) {
        var x = value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
        value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');

        this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(value);       
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [cleave.js](https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/)

```
// phone (123) 123-4567
var cleavePhone = new Cleave('.input-phone', {
        //prefix: '(123)',
        delimiters: ['(',') ','-'],
        blocks: [0, 3, 3, 4]
});
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/emirM/a8fogse1/

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel! Use **Currency Mask**, unlike **TextMaskModule**, this one works with number input type and it's super easy to configure. I found when I made my own directive, I had to keep converting between number and string to do calculations. Save yourself the time. Here's the link:

https://github.com/cesarrew/ng2-currency-mask

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" formControlName="gsm" (input)="formatGsm($event.target.value)">

formatGsm(inputValue: String): String {
  const value = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); // remove except digits
  let format = '(***) *** ** **'; // You can change format

  for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    format = format.replace('*', value.charAt(i));
  }

  if (format.indexOf('*') >= 0) {
    format = format.substring(0, format.indexOf('*'));
  }

  return format.trim();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

export class MyMaskUtil {

```
public static MASK_CEP(value: string):string {
    return value = value.replace(/^(\d{5})(\d{3}).*/, '$1-$2');
}

public static MASK_TELEFONE(value: string):string {
    return value = value.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{5})(\d{4}).*/, '($1)$2-$3');
}

public static MASK_CPF(value: string):string {
    return value = value.replace(/^(\d{3})^(\d{3})^(\d{3})(\d{2}).*/, '$1.$2.$3-$4');
}
```

}

RECEBA

*créditos Enilson Filho*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).