# Masking a text field in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-changedetection, angular2-formbuilder, angular2-inputs

I want to apply masking to fields like phone number, credit card and SSN e.t.c in Angular 2. I can't find any solution.

Masking of a field should occur when the correct number of digits entered, for example, if the user enters 10 digits for a phone number.
And if the number of digits is not appropriate then masking should occur when user clicks away from field like blur.

It would be great if anyone can share a solution for this.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like someone may have something that you'd like (https://github.com/msafi/text-mask/tree/master/angular2).  You may even be able to combine it with event handlers: `<input type="text" (keyup)="validateInput()" />`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800841/input-mask-fields-in-angular2-forms/37887432#37887432 (for the old forms though)