# Angular 2 - Binding a form control value inside a directive

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I am a newbie in angular 2 here. Just want to ask if how can I bind the `[ngFormControl]` value inside a directive? I tried using`@HostBinding('value') get value {return this.el.value}` but it just updates the `nativeElement`'s value, not the `[ngFormControl]`'s value.

I am creating a number only directive wherein it accepts a configuration on what type of number to accept (e.g negative or positive, with or without decimal). If negative is allowed, I will allow the dash symbol (-) to be inputted. But when the user only inputs a dash and no tailing numbers, once the input loses its focus (`blur` event fires), I updated the `nativeElement`'s value with empty string. The view is blank but the `[ngFormControl]` still has the value of '-'.

Here is my code for `blur` event:

```
@HostListener('blur', ['$event']) onBlur($event){
  if(isNaN(this.el.value)){
    this.el.value = '';
  }
}
```

What I want to accomplish is for the directive to edit or modify or update the value of the `[ngFormControl]` from where the directive is attached to.

Thank you! =)

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800841/input-mask-fields-in-angular2-forms/37887432#37887432

Comment: also might help https://plnkr.co/edit/hWpNz1QYCBpTzKjXtnOr?p=preview and http://www.code-sample.com/2015/07/angularjs-2-forms-validation.html

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thank you for the idea! It saved my life!