# How to split numbers in Angular?

Tags: angular

In the input I have a number:1000000 or 1000

I want to format it to: 1 000 000 or 1 000 respectively.

I tried to use a Pipe but it did not work out, what could be the problem?

```
{{  value | number : '1.1-10'}}
```

Comment: Can you show the pipe you tried to use / write ?

Comment: @rjdkolb i add to question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the number pipe like this,

```
   <h1>{{value | number:'.2'}}</h1>
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/ngDJ7CJc9V5LX4sfqyYt?p=preview)**

Comment: The demo is broken.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/5FsJ0 <-- errors in both chrome and safari. It only says 'loading...'

Comment: Thanks you! This works with h1, but how does it use this input? 
 <input id="clientCode" name="clientCode" class="col-sm-7" type="text" [(ngModel)]="job.ClientCode" placeholder="Enter Client Code" maxlength="8">

Comment: pipes are used for displaying, you cannot use it for masking, you need to implement a directive as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40348290/angular-2-issues-with-number-pipe-on-input

Comment: I try use this, but in this row:

var valArray = this.el.nativeElement.value.split('.') : [];

Error ", expected"


I just copied that code that is, what could be the problem?

Comment: did you check the plunker attached in that link ?

Comment: Yes, i see this plunker, i fix it. But when i enter a number, an error: The specified value "5,234" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce in this format, do the following:

**HTML**

```
{{  value | number : '1.0-0'}}  /* 0 decimal digits */

{{  value | number : '1.1-10'}} /*1.1-10 means: at least one digit before decimal point, at least 1 digit after decimal point but no more than 10 digits.*/
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';

...
   @NgModule({
....    
providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'fr-FR' },....
// or your country local. For the thousands delimitation as space 'fr' works
```

Output

> 1 000 000

Answer (score -1):

```
public splitNumber(humidity: number):string {
    if(humidity == 0){
      return 0+"";
    }
    var str = humidity.toString();
    var numarray = str.split('.');
    var a = new Array();
    a = numarray;
    return a[0] +"."+this.numberFist(parseInt(a[1],10));
  }
```

Comment: This just looks like a cut and paste that doesn't match the question, it doesn't do the second space for 1 000 000 for example.