# Angular2 get entire input value on keypress or keydown

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

I may be going about this wrong because I am doing something simple but my solutions are very bug prone.

All I want to do is execute a filter on a 3rd party component when input text changes (on key down).

**first approach that didn't work:**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name Fitler" [(ngModel)]="NameFilter" (keydown)="keyDown($event)" />
```

the problem is that key down executes before NameFilter is updated with latest characters, so my filter is one character behind

**second approach that didn't work**

```
keyDown(event:KeyboardEvent){
    var input = <HTMLInputElement>event.srcElement; 
    this.NameFilter = input.value + event.key; // <-- have to add the latest character
    this.filterChanged();
}
```

this sort of works but is bug prone. input.value doesn't have the latest character so i am adding it but would need to worry about odd keys etc. I'd like to avoid keyCode filtering if i can.

Is there another event ? or better way to get that value including the latest key down? (i do not want to wait for key up, or enter)

**update** this works perfectly

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name Fitler" [(ngModel)]="NameFilter" (ngModelChange)="filterChanged()" />
```

Comment: This is probably not the best approach but it's working and seems to be similar to what you're trying to accomplish http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800841/input-mask-fields-in-angular2-forms/37887432#37887432

Comment: thanks but im trying not to reinvent the wheel. it's a simple scenario i am sure is covered between angular2 and dom events

Comment: You can try `ngModelChange` instead of `keydown`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer like this? (ngModelChange)="modelChange($event)"  yes that works! just a little worried because i can't find any documentation on angular site but i'll sue it for now thanks !

Comment: ngModelChange is mentioned here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngModel

Comment: thanks! i tried searching their api documentation for it but i guess they don't include events in search indexes. this is a perfect solution

Comment: It's just an `@Output()` of the `NgModel` directive. With `[(ngModel)]="..."` you are using it implicitly. See the yellow box below https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#two-way

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `(ngModelChange)="..."`.

```
(ngModelChange)="keyDown($event)"
```

`ngModelChange` is emitted when `[(ngModel)]="NameFilter"` updates `NameFilter`.

The `()` inside `[ngModel]`) is just a shorter form (syntactic sugar) for

```
[ngModel]="NameFilter" (ngModelChange)="NameFilter = $event"
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#two-way

Comment: This do not answer the question. Its a nice approach but I'm still loking for a way to retrieve this value using keydown

Answer (score 5):

Example without `NgModel`

```
<input type="text" (keyup)="onKeyPress($event)">
```

```
onKeyPress($event) {
    console.log($event.target.value)
}
```

Comment: You are a Hero.