# Ionic3 - Can't bind to 'textMask' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-input'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to use textMask on ionic 3, but it's not working
I am getting error message (Can't bind to 'textMask' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-input') . I am following Joshmorony's tutorial https://www.joshmorony.com/improve-mobile-form-ux-with-input-masks/

[Click here to see the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqllL.png)

```
app.module.ts

 import { TextMaskModule } from 'angular2-text-mask';
 @NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    TextMaskModule 
 ],

contact.html

        <ion-input type="tel" 
           [(ngModel)]="phoneNumber" 
           [textMask]="{mask: masks.phoneNumber}" >
        </ion-input>

contact.ts

  import { TextMaskModule } from 'angular2-text-mask';

  export class ContactPage {
  form: FormGroup;
  masks: any;

  phoneNumber: any = "";

  constructor() {
    this.masks = {
        phoneNumber: ['(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/],
    };
 }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you have existing **home.module.ts** or **contact-page.module.ts** (based on the image), do the importing of TextMaskModule to them and not in the app.module.ts

Comment: I imported TextMaskModule in the contact-page.module.ts and it works fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. You saved us a lot of time. :)