# Restrict number in textbox to 2 digits (less than 100)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to restrict the user so that he can enter a positive number between 0 to 100. I have created a directive for that. In some use case, I m facing some issues.

In a table, there are text boxes where I need to restrict the user. Scenarios where it's not working:
1. If he uses tab and comes to that textbox, by default numbers are selected and if he types next number it should replace that number.

```
 import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
    // tslint:disable-next-line:directive-selector
    selector: '[appInputRestriction]'
})
export class InputRestrictionDirective {
    inputElement: ElementRef;
    isFocused: boolean;

    @Input('appInputRestriction') appInputRestriction: string;
    arabicRegex = '[\u0600-\u06FF]';

    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        this.inputElement = el;
    }

    @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onkeydown(event) {
        if (this.appInputRestriction === 'integer') {
            this.integerOnly(event);
        }
    }

    integerOnly(event) {
        const e = <KeyboardEvent>event;
        if (e.key === 'Tab' || e.key === 'TAB') {
            return;
        }
        if ([8, 9, 27, 13, 110].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1 ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (e.keyCode === 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+C
            (e.keyCode === 67 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+V
            (e.keyCode === 86 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+X
            (e.keyCode === 88 && e.ctrlKey === true)) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
            return;
        }
        if ( ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'].indexOf(e.key) === -1 ||
       parseInt(event.target.value.toString() + e.key.toString() , 0 ) > 100  )  {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
 //html code
 <td class="number-cell editable">
            <input
              [ngModel]="t.timePct"
              (ngModelChange)="t.timePct = $event; t.isDirty = true"
              type="number"
              (input)="this.calculateTotals()"
              autocomplete="off"
              appInputRestriction="integer"
              min="0"
              max="100"
            />
          </td>
```

If the no. is double-digit then in my code because of this line (parseInt(event.target.value.toString() + e.key.toString() , 0 ) > 100 ) it restrict user from typing that no. But if the previous no. is single digit then it allows the user to replace that number. I wanted that even in the first case, on tab selection it should replace the previous number.

Comment: Would it be possible to allow *entry* of any values but then use validation to confirm the value is as desired? You could either use the numeric vaidator, max validator and/or the pattern validator.

Comment: The field requirements are a bit different, but did you see the techniques presented here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800841/mask-for-an-input