# Angular 6: change Input text while typing

Tags: javascript, html, angular, input

I'm trying to format the value of an input field while I am typing into it.

```
<input (change)="test()" [(ngModel)]="testModel">
```

When I am trying this:

```
test() {
this.testModel = 2;
}
```

I would expect the visible text of my input to change to 2 on every input change. But nothing really is happening except the first character changes and console tells me the text did change (not visible though).

While when I am trying this:

```
test() {
this.testModel += 'a';
}
```

it works perfectly and adds an 'a' to the value on every type.

I'm trying to achieve that 1200 becomes 1.200€ while I am typing 1200.
Thanks

Comment: you should probably use an input mask instead

Comment: I recommend reading the angular reactive-forms tutorial:
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms
also nice in this context https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: So I found a solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37887432/5477412
Thx to @mast3rd3mon