# Create Phone Textbox into Angular Component Wrapper

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular7

I am trying to convert Phone Mask from solution below into Angular component. Does anyone know how to conduct this?  * Any answer which creates 1 similar component for Phone textbox will work.

[Mask for an Input to allow phone numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800841/mask-for-an-input-to-allow-phone-numbers)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-phone-mask

I tried, copied code into component below. Receiving errors,

- phonebox allows text to Exceed 10 characters.
- In debugging, when backspacing all characters, a character value
  still remains.

The original answer uses directive, and only works with formcontrol. Goal is to have custom company textbox component with its only styling, inputs, etc.

At the bottom, we reference stackblitz code.

**Typescript:**

```
export class CustomFieldErrorMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  constructor(private customControl: FormControl,private errors:any) { }

  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    return this.customControl && this.customControl.touched &&(this.customControl.invalid || this.errors);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-phone',
  templateUrl: './input-phone.component.html',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputPhoneComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]})

export class InputPhoneComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() MaxLength: string;
  @Input() ReadOnly: boolean;
  @Input() Value: string;
  @Input() type: string;
  @Input() Label: string;
  @Input() PlaceHolder: string;
  @Output() saveValue = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() onStateChange = new EventEmitter();
  @Input() errors: any = null;
  disabled: boolean;
  control: FormControl;

  constructor(public injector: Injector) {}
  ngOnInit() {  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const ngControl: NgControl = this.injector.get(NgControl, null);
    if (ngControl) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.control = ngControl.control as FormControl;
      })
    }}

  saveValueAction(e) { this.saveValue.emit(e.target.value); }
  writeValue(value: any) { this.Value = value ? value : ''; }
  onChange(e) { this.Value = e; }
  onTouched() { this.onStateChange.emit(); }

  registerOnChange(fn: any) { this.onChange = fn; }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any) { this.onTouched = fn; }
  setDisabledState(isDisabled) { this.disabled = isDisabled; }

  errorMatcher() {
    return new CustomFieldErrorMatcher(this.control,this.errors)
  }

  readonly errorStateMatcher: ErrorStateMatcher = {
    isErrorState: (ctrl: FormControl) => (ctrl && ctrl.invalid)
  };

  //Section from Stackblitz reference

  @HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event'])
  onModelChange(event) {
    this.onInputChange(event, false);
  }

  @HostListener('keydown.backspace', ['$event'])
  keydownBackspace(event) {
    this.onInputChange(event.target.value, true);
  }

  onInputChange(event, backspace) {
    let newVal = event.replace(/\D/g, '');
    if (backspace && newVal.length <= 6) {
      newVal = newVal.substring(0, newVal.length - 1);
    }
    if (newVal.length === 0) {
      newVal = '';
    } else if (newVal.length <= 3) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})/, '($1)');
    } else if (newVal.length <= 6) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})/, '($1) ($2)');
    } else if (newVal.length <= 10) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/, '($1) ($2)-$3');
    } else {
      newVal = newVal.substring(0, 10);
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/, '($1) ($2)-$3');
    }
    this.writeValue(newVal);
  }

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="input-wrap">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>{{Label}}</mat-label>   
        <input 
            matInput 
            [attr.maxlength] = "MaxLength"
            [value]="Value ? Value : ''"
            [placeholder]="PlaceHolder ? PlaceHolder : ''"
            [readonly]="ReadOnly"
            [type]="type ? type: 'text'"
            [ngModel]="Value" 
            [errorStateMatcher]="errorMatcher()"

            (input)="onChange($event.target.value)"
            (blur)="onTouched()"
            (change)="saveValueAction($event)"
            (ngModelChange)="Value=$event"
        >
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a demo in the stackblitz? i.e your tried code

Comment: will need code to accept as answer, thanks

Comment: code should be able to work without FormControlName,

Comment: Hi Matt can you please provide your working StackBlitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-phone-mask   this needs to be transferred into 1 component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Working [Forked StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nbs-so-angular6-phone-mask)

**TypeScript:**

```
import { Component, forwardRef, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, Injector, HostListener, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroupDirective, NgForm, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor, NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

export interface ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean;
}

export class CustomFieldErrorMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  constructor(private customControl: FormControl, private errors: any) { }

  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    return this.customControl && this.customControl.touched && (this.customControl.invalid || this.errors);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-phone',
  templateUrl: './input-phone.component.html',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputPhoneComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})

export class InputPhoneComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  disabled: boolean;
  control: FormControl;
  @Input() MaxLength: string;
  @Input() ReadOnly: boolean;
  @Input() value: string;
  @Input() type: string;
  @Input() Label: string;
  @Input() PlaceHolder: string;
  @Output() saveValue = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() stateChange = new EventEmitter();
  @Input() errors: any = null;
  @ViewChild('input', { static: true }) inputViewChild: ElementRef;

  readonly errorStateMatcher: ErrorStateMatcher = {
    isErrorState: (ctrl: FormControl) => (ctrl && ctrl.invalid)
  };

  constructor(public injector: Injector) { }
  ngOnInit() { }

  saveValueAction(e: any) { this.saveValue.emit(e.target.value); }
  writeValue(value: any) {
    this.value = value ? value : '';
    if (this.inputViewChild && this.inputViewChild.nativeElement) {
      if (this.value === undefined || this.value == null) {
        this.inputViewChild.nativeElement.value = '';
      } else {
        const maskValue = this.convertToMaskValue(this.value, false);
        this.inputViewChild.nativeElement.value = maskValue;
      }
    }
  }

  onModelChange: Function = () => { };
  onChange(e) { this.value = e; }
  onTouched() { this.stateChange.emit(); }

  registerOnChange(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onModelChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any) { this.onTouched = fn; }
  setDisabledState(isDisabled) { this.disabled = isDisabled; }

  errorMatcher() {
    return new CustomFieldErrorMatcher(this.control, this.errors);
  }

  onInputChange(event) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const maskValue = this.convertToMaskValue(event.target.value, event.inputType === 'deleteContentBackward');
      this.inputViewChild.nativeElement.value = maskValue;
      this.value = this.convertToRealValue(maskValue);
      this.onModelChange(this.value);
    }, 0);
  }

  private convertToMaskValue(value: string, backspace: boolean): string {
    let newVal = value;
    if (newVal && newVal.length > 0) {
      if (backspace && value.length <= 12) {
        newVal = value.substring(0, value.length - 1);
      }
      newVal = this.convertToRealValue(newVal);
      if (newVal.length === 0) {
        newVal = '';
      } else if (newVal.length <= 3) {
        newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})/, '($1)');
      } else if (newVal.length <= 6) {
        newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})/, '($1) ($2)');
      } else if (newVal.length <= 10) {
        newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/, '($1) ($2)-$3');
      } else {
        newVal = newVal.substring(0, 10);
        newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/, '($1) ($2)-$3');
      }
    }
    return newVal;
  }

  private convertToRealValue(value: string): string {
    return value.replace(/\D/g, '');
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="input-wrap">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>{{Label}}</mat-label>
    <input #input matInput [attr.maxlength]="MaxLength" [placeholder]="PlaceHolder ? PlaceHolder : ''"
      [readonly]="ReadOnly" [type]="type ? type: 'text'"
      (input)="onInputChange($event)" (blur)="onTouched()">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```