# Phone Number Validator In Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want these type format and extension number are optional

```
(123)-456-7890 X 12345
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Phone" min="10" max="15" class="form-control" formControlName="phone"
       mask="(000)-000-0000 x 00000"
       [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': (isSaved && contactForm.phone.errors)}">
```

Typescript:

```
phone: ['', [Validators.pattern(this.commonRegex.PhoneWithExtRegex)]],

/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})+\x([0-4]{5})/
```

Comment: give me proper output ..

Comment: what do you want?

Comment: I want input format Like (123)-123-1234 And User Add Extra Number So Do Like (123)-123-1234 x12345 Extension Number Are Optional

Answer (score 0):

You should use reactive forms as you can make changes easily and no matter how large form is, you would work around it easily. Create a form builder at the start and use its properties. And make the regex as per your need.

in your component HTML file it should be like:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="form-control" formControlName="phone"
       [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': (isSaved && contactForm.get('phone').errors)}">
<div *ngIf="isSaved && contactForm.get('phone').errors" class="invalid-feedback">
  Invalid phone number.
</div>
```

Make changes in your component ts file like follow:

```
  contactForm: FormGroup;
  isSaved: boolean = false;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.contactForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      phone: ['', [Validators.pattern(this.getPhonePattern())]]
    });
  }

  getPhonePattern(): string {
    return '^\\(?(\\d{3})\\)?[-. ]?(\\d{3})[-. ]?(\\d{4})( x \\d{1,5})?$';
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.isSaved = true;
    if (this.contactForm.valid) {
        You can call your API or whatever your process it
    }
  }
```

This is the best way to handle inputs or form I have been implementing in my project. Hope it helps and let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: what is the error? Can you show me the steps or your code?

Comment: <input type="text" placeholder="phone" class="form-control" formControlName="phone"
         mask="(000)-000-0000" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': (isSaved && contactForm.cell.errors)}">

it's My Input I trying to add format like (123)-123-1234 and also uses add more thane 10 digit so allow him to add extra max 5 digit and format like these  (123)-123-1234 x 12345

ii tried validation phone: ['', [Validators.pattern(/^\(\d{3}\)-\d{3}-\d{4}( * \d{1,5})?$/)]],

Comment: Change your code like this : phone: ['', [Validators.pattern(/^\(\d{3}\)-\d{3}-\d{4}( x \d{1,5})?$/)]],

Answer (score 0):

**install `npm install angular2-text-mask --save` and import in module file where your component in declared**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Phone" min="10" max="15" class="form-control" formControlName="phone"
      [textMask]="{mask: mask}"
       [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': (isSaved && contactForm.phone.errors)}">
```

Use this pattern

```
 public mask = [
    '(',
    /[1-9]/,
    /\d/,
    /\d/,
    ')',
    '-',
    /\d/,
    /\d/,
    /\d/,
    '-',
    /\d/,
    /\d/,
    /\d/,
    /\d/,
    ' ',
    'x',
    ' ',
    /\d/,
    /\d/,
    /\d/,
    /\d/,
    /\d/,
  ];
```

I did it please check below URL

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-text-mask-8i4v2z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: (123) 456-7890 '/
this is out put 

your format not working
i want this => (123)-123-1234 x12345

Comment: u need that type output right ?

https://prnt.sc/-YyG8kjXfWlj

Comment: No, I Need get a Number Like This Format  From Input Field

Comment: u need when i write input field 1231231234 

u get (123)-123-1234 right?

Answer (score 0):

I think using Angular directives is the way to go.
This solution looks good to me:
[Mask for an Input to allow phone numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800841/mask-for-an-input-to-allow-phone-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

<input type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="form-control" formControlName="phone" *minlength="14" maxlength="22"*
appPhoneExtMask  [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': (isSaved && contactForm.controls['phone'].errors)}">

Comment: Please, update your answer with some comments about what your code does and hot it answers the question.

Comment: Use Custom directives For This

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[formControlName][appPhoneExtMask]',
})
export class PhoneExtentionMaskDirective {
  constructor(public ngControl: NgControl) {}

  @HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event'])
  onModelChange(event) {
    this.onInputChange(event, false);
  }

  @HostListener('keydown.backspace', ['$event'])
  keydownBackspace(event) {
    this.onInputChange(event, true);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formatValue(this.ngControl.control.value, false);
  }

  onInputChange(event, backspace) {
    this.formatValue(event, backspace);
  }

  formatValue(event, backspace) {
    let newVal = event.replace(/\D/g, '');
    
    // Handling the backspace for a better user experience
    if (backspace) {
      newVal = newVal.substring(0, newVal.length - 1);
    }

    // Format based on the length
    if (newVal.length <= 10) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{1,3})?(\d{1,4})?/, (match, g1, g2, g3) => {
        return `${g1}${g2 ? '-' + g2 : ''}${g3 ? '-' + g3 : ''}`;
      });
    } else {
      // Ensuring extension part is considered
      newVal = newVal.substring(0, 10) + newVal.substring(10, 15); // 10 digits + 3 to 5 extension digits
      newVal = newVal.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{0,5})/, (match, g1, g2, g3, g4) => {
        return `${g1}-${g2}-${g3} x ${g4}`;
      }).trim();
    }

    // Apply the formatting
    this.ngControl.valueAccessor.writeValue(newVal);

    // Adjust the validation
    this.adjustValidation(newVal);
  }

  adjustValidation(value: string) {
    // Regular expression to match the phone number with optional extension
    const regex = /^(?:\d{3}-){2}\d{4}( x \d{3,5})?$/;
    const isValid = regex.test(value);

    // Apply validation conditionally based on the Smatch result
    this.ngControl.control.setValidators(isValid ? null : Validators.pattern(regex));
    this.ngControl.control.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="form-control" formControlName="phone"  minlength="12" maxlength="20"
                                appPhoneExtMask [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': (isSaved && contactForm.phone.errors)}" (keydown)="handleSpaceKey($event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[formControlName][appPhoneExtMask]',
})
export class PhoneExtentionMaskDirective {

  private navigationKeys = [
    'Backspace',
    'Delete',
    'Tab',
    'Escape',
    'Enter',
    'Home',
    'End',
    'ArrowLeft',
    'ArrowRight',
    'Clear',
    'Copy',
    'Paste'
  ];

  inputElement: HTMLElement;
  constructor(public ngControl: NgControl, public el: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event'])
  onModelChange(event) {
    this.onInputChange(event, false);
  }

  @HostListener('keydown.backspace', ['$event'])
  keydownBackspace(event) {
    this.onInputChange(event.target.value, true);
  }
  
  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (
      this.navigationKeys.indexOf(e.key) > -1 || // Allow: navigation keys: backspace, delete, arrows etc.
      (e.key === 'a' && e.ctrlKey === true) || // Allow: Ctrl+A
      (e.key === 'c' && e.ctrlKey === true) || // Allow: Ctrl+C
      (e.key === 'v' && e.ctrlKey === true) || // Allow: Ctrl+V
      (e.key === 'x' && e.ctrlKey === true) || // Allow: Ctrl+X
      (e.key === 'a' && e.metaKey === true) || // Allow: Cmd+A (Mac)
      (e.key === 'c' && e.metaKey === true) || // Allow: Cmd+C (Mac)
      (e.key === 'v' && e.metaKey === true) || // Allow: Cmd+V (Mac)
      (e.key === 'x' && e.metaKey === true) // Allow: Cmd+X (Mac)
    ) {
      // let it happen, don't do anything
      return;
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if (
      (e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) &&
      (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)
    ) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  @HostListener('paste', ['$event'])
  onPaste(event: ClipboardEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const pastedInput: string = event.clipboardData
      .getData('text/plain')
      .replace(/\D/g, ''); // get a digit-only string
    document.execCommand('insertText', false, pastedInput);
  }

  @HostListener('drop', ['$event'])
  onDrop(event: DragEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const textData = event.dataTransfer.getData('text').replace(/\D/g, '');
    this.inputElement.focus();
    document.execCommand('insertText', false, textData);
  }

  onInputChange(event, backspace) {
    if (!event) {
      return;
    }

    let newVal = event.replace(/\D/g, '');
    if (backspace && newVal.length <= 0) {
      newVal = newVal.substring(0, newVal.length - 1);
    }
    if (newVal.length <= 10) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{0,3})?(\d{0,4})/, (match, g1, g2, g3) => {
        return `${g1}${g2 ? '-' + g2 : ''}${g3 ? '-' + g3 : ''}`;
      }).trim();
    } else {
      newVal = newVal.substring(0, 10) + newVal.substring(10, 15);
      newVal = newVal.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{1,5})/, (match, g1, g2, g3, g4) => {
        return `${g1}-${g2}-${g3} x ${g4}`;
      }).trim();
    }

    this.ngControl.valueAccessor.writeValue(newVal);
    this.adjustValidation(newVal);
  }

  adjustValidation(value: string) {
    let regex = /^(?:\d{3}-){2}\d{4}( x \d{3,5})?$/;
    let isValid = regex.test(value);
    this.ngControl.control.setValidators(isValid ? null : Validators.pattern(regex));
    this.ngControl.control.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To format phone numbers in the specified format with an optional extension number, you can use regular expressions in TypeScript. Here's how you can achieve this:

```
    import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';

// Define the pattern for phone numbers with an optional extension
const phonePatternWithExt = /^(\(\d{3}\))\d{3}-\d{4}( x \d{5})?$/;

// Set up the validator using the pattern
phone: ['', [Validators.pattern(phonePatternWithExt)]],
```